# evaluate a string that is a bash if-statement

Tags: bash, text-processing, wget

My script has a function `do_command()` that prints a command and then executes it. I want to put my commands in a bash array of strings, and then print _ execute them with this function. But when I try this with an if statement it fails. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

do_command () {
    echo "$@";
    $@;
}

comms=( "wget -O test http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db" # just a download test \
        "/bin/bash -c 'if [ -f test ]; then mv test test.old; fi'"      # replace previous test \
      );

for comm in "${comms[@]}"; do do_command "$comm"; done
```

I have tried different combinations of single + double quotes, putting the bare if-statement there or as an argument of `/bin/bash`, but have not yet found a way to do it. With this particular combination, the output from the last line is:

```
/bin/bash -c 'if [ -f test ]; then mv test test.old; fi'
[: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
[: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

But if I copy and paste the printed line to the prompt, it executes without an error.

Is there a way to read an if-statement from a file/array and then execute it in a script?

Comment: You can't do that. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well I can read the `wget` command from the array, then print it, then execute it. I can also read and print the `if` statement, and I'm trying to execute it.

Comment: You can't do that. Step away from the attempted implementation. What's your end goal?

Comment: To be able to print script statements (read from another input) before executing them

Comment: So a sort of `bash -x some_file`?

Comment: Ah yes! so for a variable you can use `<<<`: first `c="if [[ a != b ]]; then echo false; fi"` and then `bash -x <<< $c`! Thank you very much!

Comment: No, not at all. You cannot reliably execute code like that. Please listen to what I'm saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144368/discussion-between-alle-meije-and-roaima).

Answer (score 1):

That `/bin/bash -c 'if [ -f test ]; then mv test test.old; fi'` will get word-split (at the unquoted `$@`) as `/bin/bash`, `-c`, `'if`, `[`, ... The argument to `-c`, the commands given to Bash to execute is that `'if`. It has an unbalanced quote, so it produces a syntax error. (The rest of the args would go to the positional parameters of the executed commands.)

It won't work with `"$@"` quoted either, as you only have one argument to the script so it'd all stay a single string.

See: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable/444949#444949)

If you want to store commands like that, you'll have to run them with `eval`:

```
execute() {
    printf "executing {{ %s }}\n" "$1"
    eval "$1"
}
cmds=("echo foo bar"
      "if true; then echo yes; fi"
      "foo=123; echo \"\$foo\""
      'echo "$(date)"'
      "echo \"what's \$foo now?\""
     )
for c in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    execute "$c"
done
```

Though with complex commands, you'll have the usual quoting hell issues.

You might consider putting the commands in functions instead, and using `set -x` to print what happens, but the output would be different.